# Can I get a programming job out of college with IT internship experience?

Tags: software-industry, career-development

For the past two summers I worked doing IT internships, as they seemed interesting and the pay was good. However after thinking about it more I realized what I really enjoy is programming.

I'll be graduating in the Spring with a degrees in CS and physics.  My GPA in computer science is pretty good and I consider myself a pretty decent programmer as well however I'm wondering will I be able to get a programming job if I only have internship experience in IT?

Comment: What did you learn in CS - data & algorithms, artificial intelligence, theoretical comp sci?

Comment: This is an unanswerable question. First off, we have no idea where you live, and second of all, how can we know if you'll be hired? We'd have to ask every single prospective employer.

Answer (score 2):

You will be graduating with degrees in Computer Science and Physics, though you didn't specify the level. Assuming that you have a bachelors degree you would meet the stated requirement for most beginning programming positions. The added minor or dual major with Physics implies additional knowledge in science and math.

Programers are hired with internships from famous companies (Google, Microsoft), major scientific labs, government agencies (NASA); but many are hired after spending the summers working in food (Pizza) or emergency response (life guards). Some only have experience with on campus positions.

Go visit with the two departments or the university career counselors, they can help with identifying  sources of post-graduate jobs. They can also help you write your resume.

Answer (score 1):

plenty of people who have no college degree and no formal computer science job are able to get jobs doing programming due to projects they've done on their own time. If you have any projects you've done over the past few years, you can apply to jobs listing these sorts of projects as your experience. You can also add in your IT experience and a list of courses you've taken or you GPA to show what you've done. It's not guaranteed, but it's been done before.